# Why is my OR Pandas filter logic not working?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter some values from my dataframe but some cases in the output do not seem to follow the filter rules.
Could there be a problem with the logic? 
I want to get entries in which either of the columns fulfill the condition (that's why I use | instead of &).

I've already tried by converting the columns to integers.

```
    datos[
       ((datos['edad'] >=21) & (datos['edad']<=68)) |
       ((datos['EdadCurp']) >= 21 & (datos['EdadCurp']<=68)) |
       ((datos['edadrfc']) >= 21 & (datos['edadrfc']<=68))
    ][["edad", "EdadCurp", "edadrfc"]].head(100)
```

[image]

For instance, entry #3 does not fulfill any of the conditions but still is part of the output.

Comment: If you're applying the same condition on all columns, try this: `df[df[["edad", "EdadCurp", "edadrfc"]].apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce').between(21, 68)).all(axis=1)]`.

Comment: I don't want all 3 columns to fulfill the condition, just either of the 3, or 2 or all. Could this be accomplished by using "any" instead of "all"?

Comment: Yes, it can. That was my mistake. s/all/any

Comment: I think you have misplaced parentheses in the first item of the 2nd and 3rd conditions.

Comment: That's right... thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your filter, I think. Try with:

```
    datos[
       ((datos['edad'] >=21) & (datos['edad']<=68)) |
       ((datos['EdadCurp'] >= 21) & (datos['EdadCurp']<=68)) |
       ((datos['edadrfc'] >= 21) & (datos['edadrfc']<=68))
    ][["edad", "EdadCurp", "edadrfc"]].head(100)
```

Note that you had `(datos['EdadCurp']) >= 21 & ...` instead of `(datos['EdadCurp'] >= 21) & ...`. Same with `edadrfc`.